# Swapping column positions in a file

Tags: python, unix, awk

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
#name   cdsStart    cdsEnd  exonCount   exonStarts  exonEnds
NM_017436   431    586    3   420,440,513,    435,500,596,
NM_001173466    720    950    4    700,752,821,823,    721,760,900,973,
```

I want to do is swap the numbers that are in column 2 and column 3 for the first number in column 5 and last number in column 6, respectively. This is my desired output:

```
NM_017436   431    586    3   *431*,440,513,    435,500,*586*,
NM_001173466    720    950    4    *720*,752,821,823,    721,760,900,*950*,
```

I asterisked the changes in the output file for clarity. What I was think of doing was splitting the file with this script:

```
with open('nonsensepositions.txt') as inf:
    with open('nonsensepositions_split.txt', 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            outf.write('\t'.join(line.split(',')))
```

and then try to swap particular columns, but I think that might prove to be challenging due to the differing amounts of columns after the split. I would then have to figure out a way to make it appear as the original file after I carry out the swapping. Is there any easier way to carry out this type of swap or do I need to split the file based on the `,` and do as I proposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ sub(/^[0-9]+/,$2,$5); sub(/[0-9]+,$/,$3",",$6) } 1' file
#name   cdsStart    cdsEnd  exonCount   exonStarts  exonEnds
NM_017436 431 586 3 431,440,513, 435,500,586,
NM_001173466 720 950 4 720,752,821,823, 721,760,900,950,
```

Comment: I love awk. Now I just need to figure out how to use sub. Thank you.

Comment: `sub(/old/,"new",target)` replaces the regexp `old` with the string `new` in the variable named `target`. To learn awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to look into getting that book.